# Make links formatted as code more prominent

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design

Since the grey background colour has been added to inline code, links are quite hard to spot.
When linking to a function's documentation I usually do it like this since it is a function it seems to belong in a code block to me):

```
[`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format)
```

Which displays as:

[`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format).

It's actually even worse on MSO...

The same thing is sort of happening in the comments here on meta.

Comment: +1 - definitely worth changing.

Comment: [`This is a link???`](http://example.com)

Answer (score 6):

I think I'm just going to bump this question here.

It has been almost two years since this has been brought up yet until now there hasn't been any status change.

Besides the bump I would also let you people (yeah devs I'm looking at you ;-) ) know that sort of the same issue is there when adding links to codeblocks to comments here on Meta. See [my comment under OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/make-links-formatted-as-code-more-prominent#comment407337_24305).

And I just noticed a bit of the same behavior when viewing the revision history on posts on main (yes I know I can do "View MD source"):

Default:

[image: link in edit without hover]

On hover:

[image: link in edit with hover]

Comment: I think it helps a lot if you refrain from using excessive *other* formatting (like useless usage of `[tag:..]`), to make the links stand out more...

Comment: @Arjan Removed, but I seriously doubt it helps like you state. Considering this question already has been around for two years without tags in it and without any status change :)

Answer (score 3):

Please be careful with underlining those links though, since that *might* make underscores in links in code hard to read. If it does, may I suggest judicious use of `padding-bottom` and `border-bottom`?

Answer (score 0):

seems sufficiently link-ified to me (at least for *unvisited* links)

[How to unbind an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508784/how-to-unbind-the-event/1508810#1508810)

MSO is an exception of course since links here in post-text are dotted underline only.

At any rate, if you feel strongly about it, I'd drop the code formatting as it's not really adding much in that case.

Comment: Huh - hadn't noticed it was different on SO. Personally I don't really care about it behaves on MSO, so I retract my statement that it needs changing!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like it, there's always the option to override it locally.

The [Stylish Plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) provides the ability to override CSS with your own partial style sheets.

Comment: I was thinking of it more for other people seeing links in answers I've posted