# Can we make hyperlinks more obvious in an SO answer?

Tags: bug, status-declined, stack-overflow, hyperlinks

I'm not sure if this has got any worse with the updated style **on StackOverflow**, but hyperlinks are extremely difficult to spot in an answer: they aren't underlined (which is a standard idiom) and the color of the text is only slightly different to that of normal text.

For an example, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558590/how-does-scalatest-syntax-work/1558725#1558725). I'm really not at all sure that the OP is going to notice the two links I've embedded in the answer. Can we have the same underlining on SO as we have here on meta?

**EDIT**: *Here is a related question about the visibility of [links embedded in code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/make-links-in-code-more-prominent)*

Comment: Jeff - care to say why this has been declined?

Comment: quote `Just underline it with light dotted line so it won't add any noise but it will 10x more recognizable`

Comment: Standard idiom? I was under the impression that the standard idiom (in the 21st century, at least) was to underline on hover, like Google, Facebook and well, SO do with their links.

Answer (score 3):

I have no problem distinguishing between the links in the answer which are in bright blue and the normal text which is black. However I must admit I use LCD's anywhere which might be what makes a difference, since CRT monitors does tend to be a lot lighter.

However, I am not sure if it is such a big issue with most users, as it has been done like this for quite some time and I have seen very few people complain about it. The other alternative is to simply change links to bright orange to fit with the rest of the site.

Comment: You see the links in bright blue? I'm pretty sure I'm not colour-blind but to me they are a gunmetal grey, barely distinguishable from the raw text.

Answer (score 2):

They looks real nice and so purdy here on Meta that it's a darn shame them pretty link dotted borders don't get out on the ranch of SOFU where it's all just waving in the breezing of a summer dress.

You'd get some links that insist on having a word or [variable in there with an underscore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/make-links-in-code-more-prominent) and throws out everything, but a little padding down the bottom should cushion it soft and well.

Comment: Reading your answer made my head hurt, for whatever reason.

Comment: Maybe it was the severe lack of scribbles?

Comment: Some freehand circles might brighten my day!