# Can we get an answer to accept on status-declined feature requests?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If I've made a feature request and [it gets marked as declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25657/can-we-make-hyperlinks-more-obvious-in-an-so-answer), can there be some auto-generated answer which just says **Declined** or something simple like that?

The reason being; *I can't accept any answer on the question as it stands* which, of course, negatively impacts my stats/perception. I just want an answer that I can accept, as clearly the thread is not going to generate any other "right" answer.

Answer (score 5):

The only answer I would like to see, on declined requests, is one explaining the decision.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that the accept rate on meta is meaningless anyway, so there's really no penalty involved.

<sub>Says the mod the with 16% rate...</sub>

Comment: In my defense, a bunch of those questions were migrated from UserVoice ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these could just be filtered out of the accept rate calculation, the same way CW questions are.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't negatively affect your reputation (unless you count the loss of +2 rep that you'd get by accepting an answer). The rest is just perception.

You can still accept an answer though -- pick any answer that you think discusses the topic the most clearly. You could even accept an answer that proposed the solution you want, even if the dev team declines to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

If you must accept something, submit your own answer and accept it.  You might consider using that answer to combine all the reasons you understand the feature was declined for, and mention that the feature is declined.

Comment: But I don't see a reason to do so...