# Can you change the CSS for links?

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make links in Stack Overflow answers more obvious?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/make-links-in-stack-overflow-answers-more-obvious)
>   [Visited links should be more visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52942/visited-links-should-be-more-visible)
>   [Can we make hyperlinks more obvious in an SO answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25657/can-we-make-hyperlinks-more-obvious-in-an-so-answer)

I think it very hard to differentiate normal text and links. I guess I am not the only one as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254724/is-there-some-tool-or-mode-for-refactoring-ruby-code-in-emacs#comment18062157_13254724) the guy in the comment section posted the same link I provided. His link is equally hard to see. I had to hover over his comment to notice it is a link.

Here is a screenshot of how I see the links (it is a bit easier to see the links in the image due to MSPaint png conversion):

[image]

When I read very fast I hardly notice them at all.

I suggest to add a consitent layout on all pages that underlines every link like on meta.stackoverflow.com (see image below).

[image]

Comment: I think links are fine the way they are. Underline in links is so 1990s.

Comment: Well, why do we have underlined links in meta?

Comment: @ayckoster Because links on meta have the same color as normal text, they had to differentiate them somehow. SO doesn't have this problem. Text is black and links are blue, it's very easy to see, even at a glance.

Comment: *"it is a bit easier to see the links in the image due to MSPaint png conversion"* What? PNG is lossless, there should be no difference between the screencap and the PNG.

Comment: @Null: Do you think that I've to test my eyes on some kind of colorblindness? Or maybe I should recalibrate my screen? I find visited links honestly said also pretty hard to quickly differentiate from plain text.

Comment: @Chichiray It is quite surprising to me that so many people are complaining about the visibility of links. I *personally* never had a problem with them, and I've used SO on dozens of different screens.

Comment: @Chichiray PS: Google "Ishihara," here's a good one: http://www.colour-blindness.com/colour-blindness-tests/ishihara-colour-test-plates/

Comment: Well, many people have color blindness to some degree (yellow-green, red-blue etc.). Perhaps you should act if many people are complaining?

Comment: See my comments here about color blindness: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/make-links-in-stack-overflow-answers-more-obvious/33619#comment444528_33619