# Link not visible in comments here on meta (on code snippets)

Tags: bug, meta, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make links in code more prominent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/make-links-in-code-more-prominent)

It's impossible to see if there is a link somewhere in a comment with a code snippet (at least on my screen).

E.g. a comment like:

```
This is some code snippet: [`rm -f /srv/stackoverflow/meta`](http://example.com)
```

Unless hovering over it.

Comment: This is some code snippet: [`rm -f /srv/stackoverflow/meta`](http://example.com)

Comment: This also happens on programmers.